# node.js how to stop a running api

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I created a script to read a growing file using "tailstream", which is working fine and code is as below.

```
var http = require('http');
var tailstream = require('tailstream');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var filename = "D:\\test.txt";
  var readStream = tailstream.createReadStream(filename);
  readStream.on('open', function () {    
    readStream.pipe(res);
  });
  readStream.on('error', function(err) {
    res.end(err);
  });

  setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('timeout completed'); 
            readStream.done();
        }, 10000); 

  //readStream.done();

}).listen(8080);
```

It is working absolutely fine and stops reading after 10 seconds as mentioned in setTimeout. I want this to be stopped from a button click on UI. Is it possible to pass a signal from UI and stop streaming ? Any suggestion would be a great help.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is UI? The page that redirected to the server or what?

Comment: This is going to be in app.js and called from $http from a html page.

Comment: $http? Please add all info neccessary...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, code is not tested (not sure what `tailstream` it is).

you should implement 2 functions for your client (browser, UI), both of them have a "jobId" query string parameter:

- http://localhost:8080/tail?jobId=1
- http://localhost:8080/stop?jobId=1

function "/tail?jobId=1" starts a `readStream` and cache it with a global variable, "jobId" is used to index the `readStream` for each request, because each request creates a `readStream` object, so you must make "jobId" unique (timestamp or uuid) for each request to "/tail". The pair call "/stop?jobId=1" search for given id and fetch associate `readStream` to stop it:

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const tailstream = require('tailstream');

var jobs = new Map();

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    let parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);

    if (parsedUrl.pathname === '/tail') { // send stream data
        var filename = "D:\\test.txt";
        var readStream = tailstream.createReadStream(filename);
        readStream.on('open', function () {
            readStream.pipe(res);
        });
        readStream.on('error', function (err) {
            res.end(err);
        });

        jobs.set(parsedUrl.jobId, readStream);

    } else if (parsedUrl.pathname === '/stop') { // stop job
        var readStream = jobs.get(parsedUrl.jobId);
        if(readStream) {
            readStream.done();
        }
        res.end();
    }

}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Thats what i call a good answer ;) , however before used in production, one should randomize the ids and add proper error handling...

Comment: Besides this, you'd better call "jobs.delete(jobId)" to remove `readStream` object after "done()" and errors handled.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stopHandler = $.noop;
stopHandler = funtion(){
 //do your stuff
}
```

call stopHandler() from UI

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I want to check this but one problem. This works when  run in separate script,  node <myscript.js> but when i am putting this code in app.js ,  and calling from ui ($http({url: '/readTfile'}), it is not working for some reasons. could someone please put some lights.